# How to get unique records using group by?

Tags: sql, subquery

Actual:

I have a table that looks below and I want a query for max(ts) of record from each index.

```
index,ts,pearson,close
1,2018-01-01 00:00:00.0,-0.0732723,1.19985
1,2018-01-01 00:01:00.0,-0.0324333,1.18989
1,2018-01-01 00:02:00.0,-0.0737444,1.17985
2,2018-01-01 00:01:00.0,-0.0832523,1.18955
2,2018-01-01 00:02:00.0,-0.0624323,1.16919
2,2018-01-01 00:03:00.0,-0.0237494,1.17789
```

Expected:

```
index,ts,pearson,close
1,2018-01-01 00:02:00.0,-0.0737444,1.17985
2,2018-01-01 00:03:00.0,-0.0237494,1.17789
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One canonical way of doing this uses `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "index" ORDER BY ts DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT "index", ts, pearson, close
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

As a side note, please don't name your columns `index`, which is a reserved keyword in most flavors of SQL.  I escaped `index` above using double quotes, though you might have to escape some other way depending on your actual database.

Comment: Most products, but not all, have index as reserved. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last record by time for each row, then a reasonable approach is:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.ts = (select max(t2.ts) from t t2 where t2.index = t.index);
```

In particular, this can use an index on `(index, ts)`.